# file path issue when running via command line versus durect URL

Tags: php, filesystems

We have a few processes that we run via the command line (CRON)
/usr/bin/php /path/to/site/root/index.php --uri=cli/fifteen/clear_apc

With a recent change to the index file:
require_once(../opt/local/config/setting.php)

PHP returns:
No such file or directory

However, running it directly from the browser (same file, path), it runs correctly, including that file:
www.site.com/cli/fifteen/clear_apc

Im wondering if there is a work around for that path issue, without having to include the entire path from root (/path/to/site/opt/local/config/setting.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working directory is different when running under cron and apache. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory, so that's why your code is not working as expected.

You can try `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "../opt/local/config/setting.php")`. This should generate an absolute path starting from your file's location.

Check out all the *magic constants* here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` can be shortened to `__DIR__` if you run PHP 5.3 or newer (which you should).